# Realistic way a character that born with 999/1000 luck stats die?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

In a world where Gods exist, a god "x" one and only job is to maintain some kind of machine or system that oversees the creation of hero of the eons.

Every eon, all gods gather and play a game called "Apocalypse" to relieve their boredom. When Apocalypse started, all kinds of "Apocalyptic event" ideas from all gods pooled and randomized to select one as the "Apocalypse's Theme of The Eon" to annihilate a planet.

This eon, god "x" felt too excited because his idea is selected, and keep thinking about it. When he tried to spawn a hero to defend a planet ( 20 years before Apocalypse ), he feels so lucky and jokingly entered 999/1000 as the stat of the new hero. While laughing, he accidentally pressed Enter/Generate. At the same time, a boy with 999/1000 luck stat is born.

"x" is so shocked and tried to correct his mistake before another god found out.

How? How to kill a character with 999/1000 luck?

When using a meteor to blast his home, an asteroid from another galaxy suddenly hit and make the meteor miss the planet.

When poisoning the water wells in the village, the wells collapsed and it keeps raining for years. The villager drank the rainwater.

Even when using god power to push a giant planet to smash the hero's planet, suddenly a giant black hole appeared out of nowhere before the planet clashed, saving the hero's planet.

**Summary :**
An OP hero with hyper luck born because of a god mistake. The god have 20 years to undo his mistake (kill the hero) whatever the cost. "How to kill this hero ?"

Edit :
I am thinking of a way to end the story.
Trying to keep killing him and rely on 0.1% is practically impossible.

To clarify and give you a rough image,
If this is a game, regular human stat is as follow :

A Newborn :

Strength: 1/100
Agility: 1/100
Intelligence: 1/100

A Nomal Adult Warrior :

Strength: 25-30
Agility: 10-15
Intelligence: 5-10

Luck Attribute is one of many hidden attributes such as :
Concentration -> Mana regen
Vitality -> Hp regen
Obviously, Luck -> is how lucky are you
and so on

Normal human limit is 100/100 in each stat.
100-200 is demi-god area.
200-500 is a minor god.
500-750 is a medium god.
750-1000 is a high god.

The hero have 999/1000 luck stats that are even higher than that of god's.
How to kill this hero? Im trying a possible ending with the hero dying. Is it possible to kill this hero?

Edit 2:
It seems everyone misinterpret 999/1000 luck.
What I mean Overpowered Luck is: a normal human that have 100/100 luck is considered pretty much have the limit of human luck, this means he is 100% lucky for a human.

Everybody said about 999/1000 about 99.9% luck, but u miss the point that human have a limit of 100 luck. 999/1000 means 999% (999/100) luck more than the luckiest human possible.

I guess the story itself is flawed? Like "how to kill the unkillable" then.
Thanks for the answer, it's been fun.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129056/discussion-on-question-by-romario-rio-realistic-way-a-character-that-born-with-9).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Going with your explanation that 999 is at the high end even for gods, and that it's not something like 99.9% but more something like 99.999999999999% (and then some) of luck:

Congratulations, you created another god. Not a hero, but a god. Now you want to kill him to cover up a mistake. That's going to be some god-laws issue right there as I'm sure the other gods will frown upon deicide.

Assuming that 999 is a world-breaking, insane, beyond-anything-reasonable amount of luck, none of the answers given so far would work. If essentially the whole universe will throw up "random" obstacles to your murder attempt, he'll be the one person to solve the "suicide yourself to save your mother" thing and "by chance" find a way to save both himself and her. He'll avoid the terrible fate that would lead to him jumping off a bridge to avoid the madness, and so on.

The one thing that no amount of luck can solve is: Time. He will go to 100, 120 years with his luck, avoiding all the things that kill you by chance, but sooner or later, the grave is where he's headed. Time is the great equalizer, the one thing that doesn't care how strong, how rich, how beautiful or how lucky you are. It's the only thing that no amount of luck can save him from, the inevitable fate of all.

So your problem is that you have only 20 years and that any attempt to hit him with rapid aging or such games would be countered by his luck. It appears that the apocalypse has to be re-scheduled. Shouldn't be a big deal for immortal beings. Wait a century more, what's the problem? Ah yes, you don't want the **other** gods to find out. Oopsie.

You can't. Frankly speaking, there is no way. Whatever you need to do to murder this guy, it will be so extreme that the other gods will notice. Waiting it out and inventing a bullshit reason ("sorry, the dog ate my apocalypse timeline.") is much, much more likely to be unnoticed than setting whatever universe-changing gears in motion that are big and unstoppable enough to bypass his luck roll.

or... of course... because you need a **story** and the logical approach above is boring... allow me to assume that his luck does not extend to "x". That "x" came to the conclusion to murder the boy is already a good indication that it doesn't. So "x" is protected from the effects of luck. That means that "x" will need to get his own hands dirty, because anything intermediate will be subject to luck. That includes any direct attempts at murder. Just going there and bashing his skull in won't work, luck will somehow interfere.

But do you know what else beats everything, at least in story logic? Love. Take a page out of the Loki book (the norse god, not the Marvel character). Turn yourself into a beautiful woman and make the guy fall in love with you. Work luck to your advantage - scoring the most beautiful woman in the whole country certainly is a lucky event, isn't it? Once you are inside the "love bubble", luck remains outside, because (at least in story logic) "love conquers all". Then make him your friend. Let him in on the whole story, he'll lap it up because he's been wondering his whole life just why he's always so lucky. Now you have an ally, a lover, who is **more lucky than the gods themselves**. And since you two are in love, your goals are aligned and **his luck will work for you**, not against you. If the other gods would certainly do something about it **if they found out**, then his luck will now protect you from them finding out. They won't. You're good. The most ridiculous things will happen whenever they are close to figuring it out.

In the end, you don't need to murder the boy, because that was never your goal. Your goal was to make sure the other gods don't find out about your mistake. You can **use** (instead of kill) the boy to reach that goal.

Comment: This is a great answer. "x" never intended to kill him, just hide his mistake from other gods. Never think it that way.

Comment: The way you could circumvent the Gods from finding out would be to let the hero leave that world in time right? The problem I see with this idea is that beauty is subjective, the personality of the God would also need to be perfectly compatible to be as lucky as you claim and the 999 luck will still have to go up against MULTIPLE high God lucks to avoid discovery... seems still a tough call.

Comment: It doesn't actually have to be as lucky, just seem as lucky. Happiness in conflict and all that. Hero will eat it up and chalk it up to "actually secretly a good thing." As for whether or not it's lucky, X is immune so it doesn't matter, according to the theory here.

Comment: @RomarioRio It's not a great answer since it's not an answer -- you asked how to kill the guy. It may be a great Frame Challenge. That's a way of saying you framed your problem in a funny way -- you could have asked how to "deal with" all-powerful luck.

Comment: @OwenReynolds But it give another idea to deal with the problem.

Comment: He'll get lucky and find a source of immortality long before he dies of old age.

Comment: Is it lucky to fall in love with an immortal being that won't grow old with you? Is it lucky to fall in love with someone who is only in it to use you? I wouldn't say so. The whole thing is just a little subjective for SE I think.

Comment: What if you bent spacetime? Place the hero's planet close to a (very big, so nothing noticeable happens) black hole (or equivalent), and time on it will tick faster due to how fast it orbits. 20 years pass for the gods while 120 pass for the hero. 
From his point of view, nothing happens. A bit of a boring solution though...

Comment: @aphid I always wondered, but wouldn't the extra gravity required to bend spacetime actually crush or burst any living things to noticeably make time pass that slow?

Comment: As a pedantic vocabulary point, the killing God / a god is known as "Deicide".

Comment: @HenryMalinowski thanks, you are right. Fixed.

Comment: @LioElbammalf the underlying assumption is that "x" is immune to the luck effect. That's why it has to be him, not some intermediary.

Comment: @causative good point. That does assume that in the background universe immortality is possible. That is still unclear in our universe.

Comment: @Rafalon this depends on the radius (=mass * constant) of the black hole. Small black holes have this shearing problem also known as 'spaghettification', but very large ones do not. In fact, you would not notice crossing the event horizon. It would be noticeable that a part of the sky is always dark. I'm not sure medieval astronomers would notice the lensing.

Answer (score 37):

Just keep trying to kill him.

A 0.1% chance of dying to any given event is good, but not that good. If the stat and it’s effects are linear (IE any given attempt on this guys life has a 99.9% chance of failure, no matter how cataclysmic the event) then all the god has to do is keep trying, though it would be useful to try a couple of thousand smaller deaths (hit by car, killed by bees, chokes on a recalcitrant grape), than only a few big-bang events.

You can work out the odds of surviving a number of  successive events as 0.999 (the odds of surviving due to pure luck) to the power of the number of events (multiply the result by 100 if you’re used to working in percentages) This is assuming the ‘luck’ resets every time and no event alters the chance of death.

After only two years of daily attempts on his life there’s a 50/50 chance his luck has run out. The odds of him surviving 20 years of daily events is 0.06%. If you try multiple things in a day obviously these chances go down.

If you want to tilt the odds in your favour then early on you can convince him/his parents/friends that he’s invincible. This will cause him to test his newfound luck to its limits even without your help. Either way it’s only a matter of time before his luck... runs out.

Comment: Additional info given. The god that trying to kill him is a minor god. Hero's luck is way higher than him ( God ). That is why even blackhole can possibly appear. It's the same logic as a newborn with 1 Strenght can infinitely hit an adult with 20 Strenght and still doing do demage.

Comment: get the hero addicted to Russian Roulette? Even if the chances are magically adjusted from 1/6 to 1/1000, he gets more shots at death than one per day

Comment: What if his luck causes the god to confuse him with someone else for the 1st 500 attempts. Then it causes the assassin responsible for the next 300 tries to become a pacifist and forget to let the employer know. What of the luck makes it seem he died in childbirth. My point is, it's tough to say what 1 "luck" event is, or where luck needs to operate.

Comment: This reminds me of "Lucky" Abrams in Blood Blockade Battlefront. He was cursed by a vampire so bad things happen to him all the time, but he's incredibly lucky, so he survives all of it all the time.

Answer (score 30):

Arrange a situation where he sacrifices himself willingly

To save his mother / girlfriend / home village, he has no alternative but to X.  (Throw himself in front of the magic grenade, or whatever.)  Bonus points if you can convince him that it was his fault the situation arose in the first place.

(I have been toying for years with the idea of a character who was supposed to die years before, but is too lucky for death to catch up - until the character momentarily casts his "luck shield" over someone he cares about, leaving himself vulnerable.)

Comment: Oooh, good one. He may be unharmed, but bad things are always happening around him. Depending on the tone of the story, the end goal could be willing sacrifice or, if going especially dark, down the rabbit hole of PTSD and worse.

Comment: The problem is always outside factors appearing random that makes his sacrifice unwilling, somehow. If even a black hole can appear out of nowhere to save his planet, something which chance is so astronomically low that it's pretty much impossible, anything can happen.

Comment: Looking at the way the OP puts it the 999 luck is more on the level of "won the lottery twice without buying a ticket". Your plan for the situation where the hero has no way out will need to be absolutely fool-proof from beginning to end, the "no way out" situation would mean that from the moment you set the plan in motion to get the hero in the right position it already has to be foolproof! Every decision, every step, every direction the hero might choose to go to would need to get him in that position. A stumble, anything arriving late should not interfere with the plan in any way. Tallorder

Comment: This was the solution for the character Teela Brown in Niven's *Ringworld* series.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what is considered lucky.

Luck is a subjective idea. For some its winning the lottery, or getting a job, meeting their love interest in a way that makes them interested, finding the house you want etc. Luck changes based on the time and place you are on at the time.

Your god knows this, so rather than keep killing the hero he tries to change what the hero considers as lucky. Imagine this god telling the hero: "the Gods are going to destroy this planet in a couple of years. You could try to stop it but it would cost billions of lives as not everyone is lucky. However if you are lucky enough you can get the technology and industry up in time to evacuate before the planet blows".

Changing the opinions of the hero has nothing to do with his luck, as anything he thinks is lucky will be what happens. Altering what he considers is lucky will only fail if the hero actively does not want it to happen and feel unlucky if his opinions are swayed anyway.

But you can go even farther. In terms of biological luck nothing is as lucky as giving your future offspring the best chances. Taking to the stars and spreading from there across the Galaxy means the hero's children will have the best chances of finding their own mates and getting healthy children, and being spread over the Galaxy also means protection against another apocaliptic event killing off all the genetics you pass down.

Being lucky enough to leave the planet or his children to leave it even without an apocalipse happening is probably one of the luckiest things that can happen to him. Screw protecting the planet. In fact, if he does manage to protect the planet and the Gods find out he has to deal with the backlash of all those Gods, and some of those Gods aren't just as lucky but also GODS. protecting the planet just means a stay of execution for the lucky guy, letting them succeed but escaping is the lucky option.

The hero will be so lucky as to see his friends and family safely, and he'll die happy at an old age.

Comment: In the Liaden series of books, the prequel stories involve the heroes fleeing the universe they live in, which is about to be inevitably conquered, for a different universe where the beings they are fleeing don't have an interest. The characters had to be insanely lucky to manage the trick. If the hero's quest is diverted, then THAT quest will be the luck-blessed one, like Neo in The Matrix who is manipulated to reboot humanity in his endless incarnations, diverted from changing the actual underlying system. +1

Answer (score 4):

### Make a character with 1000 dex to kill them.

If 999 luck is reality warper, then you need someone who has another reality warper stat to handle them.

They summon a black hole to stop them? The person runs faster than light, they run past the blackhole. A random meteor comes to crush them? They dodge. The hero punches just right to cause an earthquake? They dodge.

If they have an arbitrary ability to make people stronger than them, they can just make another.

Comment: Wouldn't the hero be lucky enough to convince the 1000 dex person to join him instead? Or have the 1000 dex person mistake an identity and think he completed his job, or have the 1000 dex person get a brain bleed at just the opportune time leaving the 1000 dex person incapable of much more than rudimentary thought etc?

Comment: No, the dex person has 1000 dex, so they can outrun diplomacy, search everyone on the planet to find the right person, and outrun their luck, since they are a stronger reality warper than the 999 luck person.

Comment: 1000 dex does not protect from bad luck. Or in this case someone else's luck. Their other stats are still "normal", so they could be unlucky enough to suffer a biological failure like heart attack, thrombosis or whatever. In this case the 999 luck would still eclipse the dex, as the guy can simply be lucky enough to cause the 1000 dex to be unlucky. Now he can't make the 1000 dex person fall and break his nek as the dex protects him, but anything else?

Comment: 999 luck can summon black holes. I wouldn't discount absurd stat's ability to modify the world. Remember, 1000 dex is the dex of a high god.

Comment: "There was an old lady who swallowed a fly..."

Comment: @NepeneNep some skills are better than others. Steven Hawking had a higher intelligence and Wisdom score than Usain bolt, but unless Steven Hawking knew about Usain Bolt's will to kill him he has no chance. He would need to apply his wisdom and knowledge to build stuff, convince others to help him etc. Similarly dex requires a conscious effort to make use of it while luck is passive. Getting killed by a falling piano is unlucky, but the piano missing you is lucky. Having a hitman die of a heart attack just before he gets you is lucky, no matter how strong/fast that person is.

Comment: You're talking about mortal stats. If Stephen Hawkings had 1000 intelligence, he might just invent a machine to destroy the universe and recreate it without Usain Bolt in it. It's arbitrary what stats can do, and if the author says 1000 dex can outrun a luck induced heart attack, it can.

Comment: If we killed him with 1000 dex character, then how we killed the 1000 dex character ? If even high gods not even have 1000 dex ?

Comment: You can hide the 1000 dex character, since they can move so fast they can evade the sight of the gods, and with 1000 dex their stealth checks will be insane. Or just kill them in their sleep. They don't have deus ex machina protection.

Comment: @NepeneNep having the ability to invent the machine and actually building it and using it are different aspects. That is why the 1000 intelligence does not guarantee success against a 1000 dex character, especially with the 1000 intelligence character still needing the non-1000 knowledge stat to actually know Usain Bolt is after them. That is why luck is superior, with 1000 dex you can move fast and hide like the best but it does not protect against the target being lucky enough that your non-1000 stats fails. Even with 100 stat health (max human level) there is a chance of death.

Comment: Create a 1000/1000 luck villan whose sole goal in life is to destroy the hero and bring about the apocalypse-- then you get to have a thrilling luck versus luck dule to the death. Your story could wrap up with the villan escaping the apocalypse themselves and coming after the gods who created them.

Answer (score 4):

**It is a risky thing, scheming against someone so lucky.**

How does luck protect?

1. The entity fails to kill me.  You covered that.

Other aspects of my luck involve the entity itsself.

2. The entity changes its mind about the killing project.
3. The entity gets busy doing other things.  More rewarding things.
4. The entity comes to harm and cannot try to kill me.  Maybe it is killed.

Comment: This story is flawed then ? Because even the thought of killing him can make the luck system start and killed us.

Comment: "The entity changes its mind about the killing project"... [Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Source_of_Magic) did that. Someone has the magical talent "can't be harmed by magic". The Demon (basically, a god) that is the source of magic leaves, taking magic with him and harming the character. The character's talent *arranges to bring the Demon back*. Your 999/1000 luck causing the god to change his mind about trying to kill the hero is a *brilliant* idea IMO .

Answer (score 4):

**Big numbers and sort of lucky**

The way to kill him is simple. Keep trying in a thousand different ways. Statistically, if you send 1000 hitman one at a time, one should do it. Of course that isn't exactly how chance works, but you can just have a billion smaller yet deadly encounters for him. Try to drop a random rock from a building to kill him, hitman, a rain, a meteorite...

But it gets more interesting in another way. If you throw 20 knives simultaneously, is it one attempt or 20? This waybyou can rack up the attempts quickly. Imagine putting him in a situation where every microsecond a canister of toxic gas has a 50/50 chance of breaking, instantly killing him. Now the odds aren't in his favour.

But lucky can be in many other ways. The guy is still human. If he goes to put his head in a working guillotine on purpose, luck would do little for him. Even if it does, in what way? Would it it considered luck if he only loses an ear? Or a leg?

What if this person notice her or his luck, starting to get a thrill out of it? Maybe the person will engage in more and more risky behavior as a talent or thrill, eventually stacking up too much that his luck won't help. After all, jumping directly into a vulcano needs probably a bit more than 999/1000 luck to survive unscathed.

Comment: This was my idea. Try to kill him a thousand times in a day and he'll die once.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. **Risk compensation** is the real killer.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a scenario where his luck just cannot come into play.

There's a really great episode of The Batman that I think might be applicable to this scenario. It's called Seconds, and it's about a man who develops the ability to rewind time 20 seconds. So, within the context of a world, like yours, where luck is a statistic, that'd be like being able to re-roll any situation until it goes his way. The way he's beaten is that the heroes split up and do something that he could only prevent if he was in two places at once, and by the time it's done, it takes him way more than 20 seconds to reverse it.

I think a similar principle can be applied here. You need to introduce something that's beyond the scope of what his powers can do for him. Be it a death-trap that cannot be circumvented, like placing him in the center of a sun or supernova or something like that, bigger than the range of any non-divine teleportation magic that could happen, or something that works with his luck, make him actually immortal so that situations where he's in danger aren't considered unlucky for him anymore, and then just toss him somewhere where he can't do anything like Kars from JoJo's Bizarre Adventure. Or, and this is a really stupid idea, create a bunch of guys with the same luck stat as him, set up in a way where their essential purpose in life is to kill him and then die, and hope for the best. As they're just as lucky as him, his luck wouldn't have an effect on them, and theirs wouldn't have an effect on his, so they're on even playing ground luck wise, and they have the numbers advantage.

That however is a probably only fitting for a comedic farce, as I'm sure you can think of many ways in which it can go very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Let him just die.

I am assuming that 999/1000 means that out of 1000 tires, he succeeds at 999. Well' those are quite bad odds to be honest. I mean, given this  [article](https://www.thebalance.com/what-are-the-odds-of-winning-the-lottery-3306232) his luck is not that exeptional.

I propose that he survives the most elaborate plot to off him, and then he suffocates while eating peanuts. Why? Because [shit happens](https://www.kidspot.com.au/news/viral-photo-shows-reality-of-kids-choking-on-food/news-story/7cfd1e4f1deca33bde7622401a421036) and statistics/luck is just the numbers game.

Comment: xD .. trying to imagine luckiest man ever existed died coz eating peanut.. it's nuts..

Comment: @RomarioRio There’s an anecdotal story about one of the people who survived going over Niagra Falls in a barrel dying six months latter because of slipping on a banana peel. These types of crazy stories are indeed nuts, but they are also exceedingly popular, especially when the lucky person is an antagonist in the story.

Comment: Fallout caps the chance to hit at 95%. So, 100% of the time there's a 5% chance to critically fail and shoot yourself in your own face.

Comment: @RomarioRio Have you heard about the Witcher series? WARNING SPOILERS

The protagonist is a bad ass monster slayer, he has slayed numerous humanoids and monsters alike. Dies because some pleb stabs him with a pitchfork. 

END OF SPOILER

Answer (score 3):

**Minor Challenge:  Is murder really the goal here?**

Consider that if there are gods, there is likely an afterlife.  Even if you managed to kill the luckiest mortal in the world, there is that infuriatingly small chance that something happens and the luckiest mortal in the world somehow self-resurrects through some means.  Probably a loophole in the afterlife unknown until now.

Your deity's goal is to fix the mistake.  Based on the question, just adjusting his stats with the Hero Generator is not going to work since the hero is already born.

Is the hero supposed to succeed at saving the world?  That might also dictate the better way to get rid of them.  Blowing up the cause of the apocalypse (by accident!) only to die from the shrapnel from the explosion would seem to tie up all the loose ends there, and be a luck-based way to die.

Of note, your hero appears to be otherwise mortal.  They will not have the raw stats to out-muscle their problems, or out think them.  Their luck might prevent a horribly messy death, but their otherwise mortal stats will get them into as much trouble as their godly luck will get out of.

#### What is Luck?

Based on general consensus, I am presuming by "Luck", one means "Good Luck".  But really, if someone is that supernaturally lucky, they will be practically cursed with luck.  And I do mean cursed in the "May you live in interesting times" sort of way.

Sure, this is the person that can randomly find a jackpot lottery ticket on the ground.  This is probably also after their home collapsed/exploded through some one in a million happenstance.  But it's all right -- they weren't there due an unquenchable taquito craving at 3 AM.  Plus they had to detour because the store they normally frequent was just robbed, so this ticket wasn't even on their regular route.  And they missed being part of that robbery because a shoelace broke and they had to replace it.

Refit the statement above to be more appropriate to the world and the idea still holds.  The hero is stupid lucky, but that also leaves them vulnerable to falling into the weirdest situations mortal life can find.  This hero literally lives the life of some ridiculous anime protagonist in all the weird stuff they will get into.

#### Removing the Hero

But removing the hero, that is trickier.  There is that stupidly annoying change that if they die, someone will try some resurrection thing on them and they are still lucky enough for it to work.

The deity could just yeet them off the planet, but they would still technically be alive and in the system.  Plus, it would open up extraterrestrial shenanigans that will end up coming back to the planet if it still needs saving.  Probably with a way to save the world made by an alien super-genius with a potato.

The best way would seem to be to engineer a situation where a non-fatal removal would be the luckiest thing that would happen.  Accidental petrification to save the world from flesh-eating parasites?  The Luckiest Statue in the World can't really affect the world much until people managed to un-petrify themselves somehow.  Perhaps everyone else recovers but the hero and the hero's statue and absurd luck protects the city that surrounds it after the end.

Perhaps the most interesting way to remove the hero is to have their luck not function properly if they actually rely on it to solve the problem at hand.  Godly luck can't be comprehended by a mortal mind so the moment they rely on it, it will only merely function at a peak mortal level.  That could be when they are vulnerable to horrible messy death.  Plot Armour that fails the moment one tries to actually use it.

#### It Was Fate

Given that a God Conference decides the Apocalypse of the Eon, there may well be a Deity of Fate there as well.  It may also be that this eon, a Deity of Luck will rise and join their ranks and has been fated as such for eons before this (if anyone remembers that far back).  But to do that, they need somebody with enough luck to fit the role and a tale strong enough to be able to lift them into the ranks of divinity.

The absurd luck stats ensures that they qualify for the mantle of a luck deity.  Saving the world likely in the most stupid lucky way is a deed that will be remembered for ages, if only for the utter incredulity of how they won.  And they will certainly be lucky enough to survive ascension into fill godhood with that luck stat.

How they luck themselves into divinity is the topic of a sequel of course

#### Conclusion

I don't think that the story is flawed in so many words.  It might not be the story that you want or are thinking of though.

Perhaps a story of an otherwise ordinary main character with OP luck that has to think their way out of their problems is a good story if done in the right tone.  The protagonist's godly luck is justified Plot Armour all things considered.

Comment: +1:  "unquenchable taquito craving"

Answer (score 3):

### Greener pastures!

Think back to one of cinema's most renowned masterpieces: [Star Trek I: The Motion Picture](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079945/?ref_=ttls_li_tt).  One lucky scientist falls in love with omniscient space probe, and departs for the endless horizons of parallel space that only he can imagine.

Build a portal that *might* reach another universe if you're really lucky.  That *might* be inhabited by gods who have more meaning in their lives than an occasional game of Dungeons and Dragons.  Only one person can go.  *Who would be lucky enough to be the lucky winner?*

When someone leaves the universe, they are not "living" in that universe.  True, they don't live fast die young and leave behind a lucky corpse, but this probably is best for avoiding unfortunate publicity.

Answer (score 2):

The most unlucky thing to ever happen to this person is that they were given a luck stat of 999/1000.

With absurd luck like that, this character has never had to struggle for anything in their entire life. There are no surprises, and realistically nothing to live for. Boring!

I would focus on the internal struggle with this character. Maybe the revelation of their luck stat being a joke would be enough to push them towards ending it all.

Comment: Welcome to the site Dom. This answer is what we refer to as a frame-challenge and perfectly valid as-such (though we generally prefer answers to be slightly longer in form, it's fine). Please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. Welcome to worldbuidling.

Comment: I did, i planned to have a depressed main character because he is so lucky that even the thought of wanting friend rice make it somehow dropped in front of him in some extraordinary way. He never have ambition, and life is so boring for him.

Comment: He will be so depressed that he tried killing himself but never can.

Answer (score 2):

Statistically if each attempt has a 0.1% chance of killing the character, then if you try 1000 times you will have a 63% chance of killing them.  If you do it 2000 times you have an 86% chance, and if you do it 3000 times you have a 95% chance of killing them.  As you try more and more attempts the chances exponentially decay towards 100%.

In general if your chances of killing them are 1/N and you try to kill them M times then your chances of killing them are about 100% * (1 - e^(-M/N)).

So basically since the chance is non-zero you can just try lots of times.
Make something life-threatening happen a couple of times a day, every day, for a few years, and eventually their luck will run out.

Comment: Might even run out on the first attempt. Just because someone is lucky doesn’t mean they cannot roll snake eyes!

Answer (score 1):

How about you present him with something he'd consider a fate worse than death? So then his super-luck causes him to die just before he'd have to deal with that horrible thing.

Comment: I did, i planned to have a depressed main character because he is so lucky that even the thought of wanting friend rice make it somehow dropped in front of him in some extraordinary way. He never have ambition, and life is so boring for him.

Comment: He will be so depressed that he tried killing himself but never can.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Caveats**

To extend a bit on my comment, a fairly clear definition of 999/1000 luck is needed here. Now, I asked and others either asked or assumed that meant something along the lines of "you need something with a 99.9% fatality rate to kill this person." You have pretty much clarified that's not what you meant, and your examples suggest a way stronger meaning of the term. In particular, the odds of being saved from a projectile planet by the spontaneous appearance of a black hole is safely rarer than a 1 in 1000 event. So, it seems safe to assume you're not looking for that probabilistic meaning.

You also say that a really lucky normal person might have a luck stat of 100/100. Well, assuming / is a division sign, 100/100 > 999/1000, so that's puzzling. Maybe you just mean that most people are in a range of 0 - 100, whereas deities have a range of 0 - 1000? I'm not sure. But your way of writing it could be pretty misleading.

Now you put some ranges out there for varying levels of gods, but by some definitions a god is inherently immortal, which would make the question moot, and I don't know of many religions with such a clear hierarchy of gods. So, we're sort of back to the definition issue.

**Actual Answer**

All those caveats aside, I think there's basically one answer that I could give that doesn't require several levels of clarification. If someone is basically invulnerable to not just random bad luck, but even to bad "luck" that someone else deliberately inflicted on them, then their going to have to be their own undoing. I can't believe I'm using this example, but the Disney movie Hercules has this exact issue because Hercules is invulnerable to anything Hades throws at him. So Hades takes a hostage and extorts Herc to give himself up.

Now, maybe you say "my guy is so lucky Hades would just fail to capture his lover." Well, then could your protagonist be tricked? Maybe lured into something they think is good? Could they agree to be given a drug with the promise that it will take away all pain forever, and it does because it kills them? What about their will to live. Could they be made suicidal? You'll have to decide exactly what luck protects this character from, but your answer is probably some version of the villain indirectly leading them to death instead of killing them outright.

**Another Option**

Edit: One other option. Does the god have a higher luck stat than the character with 999/1000 luck? What if the god said to the other gods "Swear to me that if I fail, you will kill me." Now the god's luck would presumably be on the side of saving said god, and that luck would favor the 999/1000 character dying. So the god could go down to the 999/1000 guy, and personally try to kill the 999/1000 guy. Now their lives are both on the line and I assume the luckier one wins?

It all depends on how you want luck to work. But this feels like one of the more self-consistent options.

Answer (score 1):

## Make him even more lucky!

Reading your update, it looks like the problem is that his luck is 999/100.  That is, humans are supposed to have luck scores ranging from 0-100, and his stat is a world-breaking 999.

This happens.  A famous example is Civilization, in which a bug allowed the pacifist Ghandi to achieve an aggression score of 255 out of 14.

**The solution is to do something that provides him with a permanent bonus to luck.**

Why?  Well, having luck range from 0-100 implies there's a cap on it.  And stat caps imply something's enforcing the cap.  And we all know that such enforcement only occurs when the stat is increased!  The way it works is that the stat is increased, then checked against maximum.  If it's above the allowed max, it drops to the max.

So if the god gets a unicorn to nuzzle the hero, or sends a Catholic nun to give him a blessing, or some such, and his luck increases to 1003 / 100, then the universe will promptly notice that his luck is over the maximum of 100, and drop it down to that level.  The hero is now exceedingly lucky, but not world-breakingly so.

At that point, the god can just sidle off whistling and hope none of the other gods notice that someone was born with a luck value at cap.

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: The Civ bug's most likely a myth, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Gandhi

Answer (score 1):

### Time Dilation

Does he need to die, or is it sufficient that his existence goes unnoticed long enough for it to become moot?

Send him somewhere at relativistic speeds. Put him near a black hole. Make sure that being in one of those situations is a huge benefit to him or his loved ones (being hidden from an apocalyptic game between gods seems pretty lucky to start), then make sure that he can't return from whatever isolated region of spacetime he's in until it no longer matters.

Answer (score 1):

What an occasion to reflect on the nature of luck.

---

### Plot twist - lucky guy destroys the world

What does luck truly mean in your world? Does the flawd human **always get what he wants** or does his **luck intervene with his plans**, letting the opposite happen from what he wanted, **if it is best for him?** Can he just not be harmed directly or is it granted that he stays sane and happy and makes the right choices?

There is the saying *be careful what you wish for because you might get it*.

Just look at *Homelander* from *The Boys*, *King Joffrey Baratheon* or *Killgrave* from *Jessica Jones*. **Don't get rid of your hero. Just show him that he can do *whatever* he wants and get away with it.**

[Dom's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/211115/67222) is similar.

Him ultimately destroying the world, always having got what he wanted instead of what would have been best for everyone is actually the 0,1% time his luck is not working out.

---

### Guardian god

Just to make it more colorful - does the 999/1000 stat simply make the hero more lucky on an abstract level or does it **turn god x into the hero's reluctant, overstrained guardian angel** who is obliged to step in and save the hero from the very traps he layed out for him (and getting his own butt kicked in by them)?
Until he realizes, he can work as kind of a shoulder devil to set the hero in his destructive path.
Maybe all the wrong-gone attacks backfiring at god x are enough for him to give up the whole thing in need of a hiatus, leaving it to the next chosen god and his apocalypse an eon later.

---

### Plot twist 2 - lucky guy becomes unlucky out of sheer luck

As this seems to be a terrible fate for the hero, the 999/1000 **luck of the newborn hero** immediately kicks in to prevent that from happening **in the very moment the god presses *enter***.
A **lucky accident** happens, **somehow rotating the dial up** by 2 and turning the hero into a happy jinx with a **score of 1/1000**.
(Basically the approach of *Breaking Dawn Part 2* with  the internecine final battle turning out to be a mere vision of a battle that never happens).
And maybe the same accident **also rotates the dial for the date of the apocalypse**, resetting the clock to the beginning of a new eon before the next apocalypse.
Wilk already [mentions that the luck could interfere with the gods](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/211063/67222) and the [animated short film *Zing*](https://youtu.be/BETa92ALukA) has a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is thinking of only big flashy ways to kill someone.

People die from tripping and falling, random infections, things falling on them, being innocent bystanders, mechanical failures in their vehicles, being kicked by horses, contracting rabies from some random dog bite, getting stung by jellyfish or insects, choking on food, carbon monoxide from badly maintained furnaces, chemical exposure at their workplace, drowning, allergic reactions, whatever.

There are literally thousands of things that could kill a person, and if they all kept happening, however lucky a person is, one will get through. And only one needs to get through. No planet tossing required.

The other issue is that I suspect you're combining events. If the man is a soldier who has been through several battles, as an example, is the 99.9% chance of survival related to the war in total or for each individual threat during said war?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be the story you want to write, but if you want somebody who is impossibly lucky (i.e. beats all odds) to die, then you have to convince them to kill themselves. Being impossibly lucky might protect them against all manner of accidents, assassination attempts or "acts of God", but luck alone can't save them from suicide - arguably, it would make their suicide attempts very likely to succeed.

Comment: There is some elemt of luck you can't control. From my understanding, a super lucky guy wishing that there is no boss loot when killing a boss will fail. Luck stat is given by the "Universe" thus he can't rewrite rules given by the universe. I think even when he tries to kill himself, the "Universe" will try to save him.

Answer (score 0):

Let his luck work for you. Create a situation where the luckiest thing that could happen to him is to die.

Though really, if he were that lucky, "x" never would have noticed his mistake, or for whatever reason the gods wouldn't be trying to kill him.

Answer (score 0):

The god just needs to have a conversation with the hero. “Look, my friend, you’re an accident, and I don’t mind you existing, but please try to stay uninvolved in the apocalypse game or else things between the gods will get so contentious, not even your luck will save you and those you care about.” The god will need to use its level 1000 charisma to do this convincing. Once staying hidden and isolated becomes the hero’s goal, then the heroic luck works with the god plans instead of against them.

Answer (score 0):

*Note : It's technically a frame-challenge which yet answers your problem (giving an end to your story). Yes, I know you want them dead but I wish to show you other interesting timelines out there :).*

### Match your goals and send/hide them away.

As written, there's a confusion between your god's goal and the hero's one. Your hero's goal (and their luck's) is to live and be happy. Your god's will is to not have the hero discovered, which means not having the hero at the same time as the apocalypse. Killing is an option, but it goes against the hero's goal. So instead, send or hide them away!

This might come to the conclusion of hundreds of failed murder attempts, where the god got bored of yelling again and again "[I'll get you next time, hero! Next time!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Gadget_(1983_TV_series))" while sitting in their CEO chair and stroking their cosmic cat.

You've got plenty of options, but the main thing is to be as honest and friendly as possible, as any intent to subvert the hero's deep goals will subvert the luck's one, which could be considered as omniscient regarding what is best for the hero. I'll list some alternatives them here :

- Send them back in time so they can die of old age *before* the Apocalypse happens. Make sure they understand the luck they have to be able to live peacefully when they would have faced the end of times if they stayed in the present, give them anchors to grab on emotionnally, and they should be fine.
- Sending them forward in time after the Apocalypse might be tricky but possible. Tell them you're giving them a chance to rebuild the world. Give them help in doing so, and make them understand the Apocalypse was unescapable. They'll be feeling like a true hero, something which can be favorable in an anyway dire time.
- Sending them in a secured and hidden space, like your god's doghouse (maybe something better than that, though :p). There, they'd be guaranteed to be happy for a very long time, and no murder attempts are to be made anymore against them. Who tried to kill them so much, anyway ;p?

This kind of thing is bound to happen at some point, because, well... If you're truly lucky, could you really find favorable for you to face a full array of angry gods AND an apocalypse as you have just reached adulthood? Your luck might not be enough to turn the tables around at that point, so it might be better to side with one of them before the storm comes and find shelter through their help. Plus, since they're so lucky, any of the helping god's actions will be amplified by tenfold, making the act of hiding the truth so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

### Frame challenge: Send him to go kill the "God of Luck".

If he wins, then the God of Luck won't know anymore until you make him the Luck God out of Rite of Caste rules.

If he loses, then the God of Luck removed the evidence for you, and you just have to persuade the God of Luck that it's just his nemesis, the "Demon of Bad Luck", who intervened.

This could be an issue if God X *is* the [God of Luck](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiredToHuntYourself), but that does help reduce the requirement to have to lie to the God of Luck as to why the Hero tried to kill him.

Answer (score -1):

If you think about it, his luck is literary 1, 100% or 1000/1000. Chances of another asteroid to hit your killer asteroid or a black hole to appear out of nowhere are many orders of magnitude lower than 0.1 and so his luck must be much more.

The way to get rid of such a lucky guy is to create space where he would be good and move him there so he doesn't stand in the way. He will eventually  dies of old age.

Comment: Mathematically , this is wrong, because mathematically there is a huge difference between 999/1000 with 1000/1000 , because 1000/1000 can make some formula divided by 0 or undefined.

Comment: @i'mashamedwithwhatiasked, please learn math. 1000/1000 is just 1 or absolute certainty. There is no division by zero. The point is that be it 1 or very close to one, the luck of the guy is unbeatable. Chances for a blackhole to appear out of nowhere are so close to 0 that we probably can't write so many zeroes after the decimal point in the comment section.


If you don't like the answer, then fine. But you can now be ashamed also of your comment and the -1 you gave ;p